# NullReference on enter key press within Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit in a dateTimePicker

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xceed

I am getting a 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll, exception, at stack location Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Core.Primitives.DateTimeUpDownBase`1.OnPreviewKeyDown().

This happens when I enter a date, in a valid format, and hit the enter key.

I have seen a few documented errors that are similar to this, but were due to a Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit v1.9 bug and has been since fixed.  I am using v2.2 . 
Below is my xaml for the DateTimePicker in question.

```
<Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left">
    <xctk:DateTimePicker
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Format="Custom"
                    FormatString="{lex:LocText MAIN.Localization:Filters:DateRangeFilterFormatString}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                    Margin="0,0,1,0"
                    ShowButtonSpinner="False"
                    TimePickerVisibility="Hidden"   
                    Value="{Binding MinimumDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Keyboard.PreviewKeyDown="keyDownEventHandler"
                    Watermark="{lex:LocText MAIN.Localization:Filters:DateRangeFilterWatermark}"
                    Width="100"/>
</Grid>
```

EDIT:

I actually dont want the enter keypress to do anything on this control anyways, so I'm attempting to catch the event.  I added a keyboard event in the above code.  It is catching the events when im typing in a date, but when I hit enter, the error is happening before it even catches the enter key event.

Comment: Are you sure your `DateTimePicker` instance is initialized?

Comment: Yea i have a submit button working with this when i click on it, but when hitting the enter key it bombs on me.

Comment: Now im trying to just intercept the enter keydown event and handle it.  Im catching all other key events but im getting the same error before its even handling the event now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For the record, I work w/ OP, and we figured it out.  Just want to answer the question in case others run into it.*

The `DateTimePicker`'s default control template has a `WatermarkTextBox` in it (`PART_TextBox`) that represents the underlying text area.  In the `OnPreviewKeyDown` handler of the `DateTimePicker`'s base class, the code looks for the binding on the "Text" attribute of that text box, like so:

```
BindingExpression binding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression( TextBox, System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.TextProperty );
binding.UpdateSource();
```

In our custom template, we were not setting the `Text` attribute of the `WatermarkTextBox`,  so that meant `binding` was null in the code above.

We fixed it by adding a binding to the Text attribute of `PART_TextBox` in our custom `DateTimePicker` template, so now it looks like this:

```
<xctk:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" 
                       Background="Transparent" 
                       BorderBrush="Transparent" 
                       Grid.Column="0" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                       Watermark="{TemplateBinding Watermark}"
                       Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
```